# Read SAS file to get meta information

Tags: python, apache-spark, sas, pyspark, databricks

Very new to data science technologies. Currently working on reading a SAS File (.sas7dbat).

Able to read the file using :

```
SAS7BDAT('/dbfs/mnt/myMntScrum1/sasFile.sas7bdat') as f:
    for row in f:
      print(row)
```

Row prints all the data.

When we view SAS files in SAS viewer we can see metadata E.g. Label Information & variable (column names) used on actual data

How can I read this metadata in Spark (Databricks) using Python ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Spark external package called `spark-sas7bdat` for reading `sas_file_name.sas7bdat`

Here is how to install it into Spark Application
https://spark-packages.org/package/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat
and some examples on its github page
https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat

Then just using Spark read method

```
spark.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark")
          .load("path to the sas_file_name.sas7bdat", inferLong=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [pyreadstat](https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat)?

It can directly read metadata.

```
    import pyreadstat

    df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('/path/to/a/file.sas7bdat')
```

Answer (score 1):

Most data analysis in Python is done using the pandas library which has a method called 'read_sas' which preserves the meta-data unless you are being ordered to use spark I strongly recommend pandas. Here is a set of instructions for SAS users: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/pandas-for-sas-users-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the link, tried to read the data in to a dataframe but still not able to access metadata. I referred to examples from here : http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RandyBetancourt/PythonForSASUsers/blob/master/Chapter%2011%20--%20Panda%20Readers.ipynb   I am executing the script in databricks Python notebook

Comment: In that case not sure what you mean by metadata. What I understand to be metadata is the column names...

Comment: When I open sas7dbat file in SAS viewer , I see two tabs one with actual data and another tab called "Library" which holds all information about columns e.g. Lable . type etc. I am trying to capture data from "Library" using python .. Adding a screen shot for the reference

Comment: Ahhn! Light dawns! Right, A thing to look at: there is a pysas module documented at  https://sassoftware.github.io/saspy/getting-started.html#existing-sas-data-set

Comment: The other thing you could look at is using the pandas read_sas method with 'itterator=True' and reading all tabs from a for loop over the reurned iterator

Comment: Thanks , tried both suggestions. I could not find a function that will read metadata from sas7 files

Comment: I think it would help you if you stopped distinguishing metadata from data and just regard it as another data set to be read. As such it should be available via the itterator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested on `metadata` only, you can use [`pyreadstat`](https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadstat_documentation/_build/html/index.html) passing `metadataonly` parameter as `True`, it will not read any data, but just the metadata, so size of the file is going to have no impact on the amount of time required to read the metadata.

```py
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('/dbfs/mnt/myMntScrum1/sasFile.sas7bdat', metadataonly=True)
```

*Note that df will be an empty dataframe when `metadataonly=True` is passed, you may want to omit this if you want both the data as well as the metadata*

You can access variable labels using `meta.column_names_to_labels`, it will give a dictionary where variable name is the key and variable label is the value.

Other useful metadata are: `metadata.number_columns`, `metadata.number_rows`, `metadata.file_encoding`, `metadata.file_label`, etc.

You can find the complete list of available metadata at [pyreadstat documentation](https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadstat_documentation/_build/html/index.html#metadata-object-description)